# How does @Data in lombok creates Constructors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I already read a lot of questions here and still couldn't understand how this works and gives no error. By my logic `@Data` creates a `RequiredConstructor` if it has `final` fields. `@Entity` needs a `noArgConstructor` so I made that too.
This is my `User` class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String fullname;
    private final String street;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final String zip;
    private final String phoneNumber;

}
```

But now in another class if I want to make a new `User` object, like below, I can't.

```java
public User toUser(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    return new User(username, passwordEncoder.encode(password),
                fullname, street, city, state, zip, phone);
}
```

##### Edit:

I added `@RequiredArgConstructor` to `User` class and now it doesn't give me errors. Problem is fixed but I don't understand how does it even work.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `@NoArgsConstructor`, it overrides the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` from `@Data`, which forces you to specify it.  If you have final fields, though, you do not want to use a NoArgsConstructor because, after construction, there is no way to set them so they can never have a value.

Also, just a note that you really DO NOT want to use @Data with @Entity, mainly because of the EqualsAndHashcode that come with it.

Comment: thanks for that really helped me understand, also with that NoArgsConstructor can i just make it protected to just decrease the use(cant make private as jpa needs protected or public)

Comment: Ideally, your entities will just be pojos.  The easiest is to drfine your fields as private, dropping the final modifier, and have getters and setters.  My entities contain three annotations, Entity, Getter, and Setter.  You can add AllArgsConstructor if you like, but you'll want to accompany it with NoArgsConstructor to satisfy your ORM.  You can use RequiredArgsConstructor without final fields, just annotate the fields that you want in your constrictor with NonNull.

Answer (score 1):

`@Data` isn't the same as `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. It will make the required args constructor for you **only if no constructor is written**. Here, you *did* write a constructor - `@NoArgsConstructor` does this.

Because you have the no-args constructor. You can add `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and now lombok will also make that one.

It's bizarre to have the no-args constructor here, as it would just init all fields to `null`. JPA is confused about what entities represent and doesn't give clear answers. If you think a `User` instance represents a User, lombok's equals is mostly fine, but you should exclude the ID field, as that is an implementation detail for storing user objects in databases and not an inherent aspect of a user object's identity. Of course, that does mean one simple equals call queries your entire database out, but that's a natural shortcoming of JPA.

Alternatively you could say that an instance of `User` represents *a row in the database*, in which case the only way to write an exactly correct equals implementation that fits both that meaning and the contract of `equals`, is this bizarroworld construction:

- If `id` is `null` (i.e. you created a new instance and haven't saved it with JPA yet), then its equals impl is: `return this == o;` - as in, it can only be equal to itself, even if **every field is identical** it cannot be equal to another. After all, if you `save()` both, you'd get 2 rows.
- If `id` isn't null, equality is defined **solely** by `id` and not anything else, for the same reason - if you were to modify one, fail to modify the other, and then invoke some save() calls you still end up with only a single row.

JPA tutorials and guidelines in my very limited experience (I do not use JPA) tend to just do whatever they please and it's rarely consistent with either pragmatism (don't cause "query the world" issues) or the equals spec. Lombok's equals may not be what you want for JPA stuff. Then again, there really isn't any equals implementation that 'works' (it'll have some sort of highly surprising and undesired behaviour).

NB: I'm one of the core lombok developers.

Answer (score 0):

`@Data` creates a `RequiredArgConstructor` **only** if there are `final` fields present and if no other constructor is being specifically made. I did make a `noArgconstructor` using `@NoArgConstructor` so it won't make a required constructor and we need to either make it or use `@RequiredArgConstructor` to initalize final fields as not null.